# Using variables in SQL

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL newb here. Sorry, this is probably trivial.

In essence I need to grab an arbitrary value from a local table, then use it in the WHERE clause of a SELECT I fire against a remote table in order to return rows that I'll insert back to the local table:

"Give me all rows in the remote table where the timestamp value in f1 is newer than the maximum timestamp value for f1 in my local version of the same table"

Something like this, sorta:

```
DECLARE @variable timestamp;
@variable = SELECT MAX(f1) from Foo;

INSERT INTO Foo SELECT * FROM (dblink('conn', 'select * from RemoteFoo WHERE f1 > @variable') as
t
( f1 int, f2 timestamp)
```

How do I approach this in postgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've got to go out via dblink anyway, I'd probably wrap it in a function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_remote_foos() RETURNS int ...
```

With plpgsql you can more or less write the code in your example. The signature above assumes you want to return the number of rows inserted. Full details of plgsql in the manuals - keep an eye out for the quote_ident and quote_literal functions in that section too. Not vital for a timestamp but will be useful in other cases.